# returning to fragment with tabhost causes silent fail

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have 3 fragments with tabhosts in them.

If I go to any one of the 3 fragments I see everything working in the fragment perfectly. If I then go to another fragment with a tabhost then doesn't show the tabs, doesn't throw exceptions, doesn't do anything at all. I can switch between a tabhost containing fragment and one that doesn't contain a tabhost and back it still works, it is only when I switch between 2 of the 3 fragments and once it is in this state there seems nothing that changes it.

Is there anything I have to do in onDetach() in the fragment, I've attempted clearall() and other things in the onDetach() and this weird situation still persists...???

Is this a known bug in the support library or is there some information that I am missing..???

R.

Comment: Would help the community if you can include your codes.

Comment: I spent the morning attempting to replicate the issue in a minimal app.

A co-worker changed all the Fragments to support fragments and the problem went away.. It seems that using Fragments and support fragments causes really weird effects without failures or crashes..

Answer (score 0):

Case closed for now... Seems Fragments and support.Fragments in the same app are a very bad idea.

Comment: That's certainly true.  You can't mix them. Also beware of using `getFragmentManager` and `getSupportFragmentManager`. The former accepts the parameter Fragment and it'll report an error if you pass it a support.v4.Fragment and vice versa.

Comment: Also, it's recommended you use TabLayout and ViewPager.

Comment: @Regan Tag this as correct answer for the record. ;)